# HTML-How can I make a button stay in a fixed position after one beside it is removed?

Tags: html, css, button, positioning

I have two buttons

```
<button class="upgradebutton1" id="upupgrade1" onclick="browse_aww()">Browse /r/aww</button> <pr id="priceuno"> 5 </pr> <img id="upvotepicture" width=13px src="http://image.spreadshirt.com/image-server/v1/designs/12018562,width=178,height=178/Upvote-style-arrow.png"></img> 

    <button class="upgradebutton1" id="downupgrade1" onclick="grow_a_neckbeard()">Grow a neckbeard</button> <pr2 id="price2"> 5 </pr2> <img id="downvotepicture" width=13px src="http://wp.iosfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Down-vote-arrow-237x250.png"> </img>
```

Whenever I click the browse_aww button, the grow_a_neckbeard button slides over where the first button used to be. This is a problem with all of my upgrade buttons on the page. I've tried using css to set the position to Absolute, but that does nothing and glitches the entire thing.

Any and all help is appreciated

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/DayDreamKiddo/zk6F4/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `position` to `absolute` you remove the box from the normal flow, so the other elements arranges like it never existed. You should create an identical box to replace the old one, but I think it's easier to simply disable the button, or at least set its `visibility` to `hidden` (which doesn't affect the normal flow).

Answer (score 1):

use visibility:hidden rather than display:none to maintain a hidden elements position in the flow

Answer (score 0):

Do hidden:visibility it worked for me.